# Name for reversed main diagonal of a non-square matrix

Tags: matrices

Consider the matrix

$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
$

Then the main diagonal elements are $1$ and $4$. I want something like the reversed main diagonal elements, $3$ and $6$, starting not from index $(1,1)$ collecting all elements but from $(n,m)$ in a matrix of order $n\times m$. Is there a name for that (since there is one for the main diagonal I thought maybe there is one for this too)?

Answer (score 2):

I would call $[3,6]$ the *first subdiagonal* of the matrix.

Comment: Could I also say last subdiagonal?

Comment: @DaPhil Last diagonal, to me, would be more ambiuous, since it could also be $[5,2]$. But that's just me.